# Deleting a record in a table

Tags: php, laravel-5

**Using Laravel 5.2.45**

I'm fairly new to Laravel and PHP in general, so I'm making a phonebook project, where I store contact info about people.

I have a table, named 'contacts', in my database named 'phonebook'.

I have a view with a form to record new entries in this table.

this is the view:

**phonebook.blade.php**

```
....... CSS and stuff here .......
<body>
    
            <h1> Contact Form </h1><br/>
    
                        {{-- FORM --}}
    
            <form method = "POST" action = "contacts">
    
                {{ csrf_field() }}
    
                <div class = "form-group
                    @if($errors->has('name')) 
                        has-error
                    @endif"> 
                    <label for = "name"> Name </label><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "name" class = "form-control" name = "name" placeholder = "Name your Name" value = "{!! old('name') !!}">
                    @if($errors->has('name')) 
                        <p class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p> 
                    @endif
                </div><br/>
    
                <div class = "form-group 
                    @if($errors->has('lastname')) 
                        has-error
                    @endif"> 
                    <label for = "lastname"> Lastname </label><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "lastname" class = "form-control" name = "lastname" placeholder = "Name your Lastname" value = "{!! old('lastname') !!}">
                    @if($errors->has('lastname')) 
                        <p class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('lastname') }}</p> 
                    @endif                        
                </div><br/>
    
                <div class = "form-group 
                    @if($errors->has('email')) 
                        has-error
                    @endif">
                    <label for = "email"> E-mail </label><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "email" class = "form-control" name = "email" placeholder = "somesomething@email.com" >
                    @if($errors->has('email')) 
                        <p class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p> 
                    @endif
                </div><br/>
    
                <div class = "form-group 
                    @if($errors->has('phone'))
                        has-error
                    @endif">
                    <label for = "phone"> Phone Number </label><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "phone" class = "form-control" name = "phone" placeholder = "I'll call you">
                    @if($errors->has('phone')) 
                        <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</p> 
                    @endif
                </div><br/>
    
                <div class = "form-group"> 
                    <label for = "address"> Address </label><br/>
                    <input type = "text" id = "address" class = "form-control" name = "address" placeholder = "I'll even visit you" value = "{!! old('address') !!}">                        
                </div><br/>
    
                <div>
                    <button type = "submit" class = "submit"> Submit Information </button>
                    <a href="contacts"><button type = "button"> View Contacts </button></a>
                </div>
            </form>      
        </body>
    </html>
```

When I record a new entry, I get redirected to the view where I can see the table.
Structured in a simple way, this is the view:

**contacts.blade.php**

```
....... CSS and stuff here .......
<body>

        <h1> Contacts </h1>

        <br/>

        <div>
            <a href = "phonebook"><button class = "ret" type = "button"> Add New Entry </button></a>
        </div>

        <br/><br/>

        <table class = "contacts">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> ID       </th>
                    <th> Name     </th>
                    <th> Lastname </th>
                    <th> E-Mail   </th>
                    <th> Phone    </th>
                    <th> Address  </th>
                    <th> Edit     </th>
                    <th> Delete   </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach($contact as $contact)                                                      
                    <tr class = "tableBody">
                        <td class = "id">       {{ $contact->id }}                                          </td>
                        <td class = "name">     {{ $contact->name }}                                        </td>
                        <td class = "lastname"> {{ $contact->lastname }}                                    </td>
                        <td class = "email">    {{ $contact->email }}                                       </td>
                        <td class = "phone">    {{ $contact->phone }}                                       </td>
                        <td class = "address">  {{ $contact->address }}                                     </td>
                        <td class = "edit">     <a href = "edit"> Edit </a>                                 </td>
                        <td class = "delete">   <a href = "delete"> Delete </a>                             </td>
                    </tr>                       
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <br/>
        
        <div>
            <a href = "phonebook"><button class = "ret" type = "button"> Add New Entry </button></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Paying attention, you'll see I have a Delete Link in my table, which I want to use to, well, delete the record in that given row.

To do this, I have a delete view, which is loaded after a piece of code in the `destroy()` function, provided in the controller I did using the artisan console

This is my routes.php file, with comments

**routes.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Contact;
use App\Http\Controllers;


// default welcome view from Laravel
Route::get('/', function ()
{
    return view('welcome');
});

// getting the routes from the controller
Route::resource('contacts', 'ContactsController');

// getting the form from the controller, which is in a .blade.php view
Route::get('phonebook', 'ContactsController@index');

// showing the table in a .blade.php view
Route::get('contacts', 'ContactsController@tab');

// the route to post the contact in the table, using the form in the phonebook.blade.php
Route::post('contacts', 'ContactsController@create');

// routing to the destroy function in my controller
Route::get('delete', [
    'as' => 'delete', 'uses' => 'ContactsController@destroy'
]);

// getting the edit.blade.php, not working
// permeate the inputs of name, lastname, email, phone and address
// with the same inputs we have in the row of our table
Route::get('edit', function()
{
    return view('edit');
});
```

Maybe the error is in my route, that is why I'm pasting it here as well.

And this is my controller, overall

**ContactsController.php** with comments

```
   <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Contact;
    use DB;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    use App\Http\Requests;
    
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
    use Validator;
    
    
    class ContactsController extends Controller
    {
       // showing the form in the phonebook.blade.php
        // the form is structured using html and stuff
        public function index()
        {
            return view('phonebook');
        }
    
        // showing the table where I save my contacts
        // simple view stuff
        public function tab()
        {
            return view('contacts');
        }
        
        // the parameters to save my contact, with errors and stuff
        //working since day one
        public function create()
        {
            $rules = array(
                'name'      => 'alpha|min:3|max:15|required',
                'lastname'  => 'alpha|min:3|max:15',
                'email'     => 'required|unique:contacts,email|email',
                'phone'     => 'required|unique:contacts,phone|alpha_num|between:3,25',
                'address'   => 'max:255',
            );
    
            $messages = array(
                'alpha'     => 'The :attribute must contain only letters.',
                'max'       => 'The :attribute must have a maximum of 15 letters.',
                'min'       => 'The :attribute must have at least 3 characters.',
                'required'  => 'The :attribute is really important. We are storing your contact info after all...',
                'email'     => 'The :attribute must be a valid e-mail format address.',
                'numeric'   => 'The :attribute must contain only numbers.',
                'between'   => 'The :attribute content must have a lenght between 3 and 25 characters.',
            );
    
            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
    
            if ($validator->fails())
            {
                $messages = $validator -> messages();
    
                return redirect('phonebook')
                    ->withInput()
                    ->withErrors($validator);
            }
            else 
            {
                $contact             = new Contact;
                $contact-> name      = Input::get('name');
                $contact-> lastname  = Input::get('lastname');
                $contact-> email     = Input::get('email');
                $contact-> phone     = Input::get('phone');
                $contact-> address   = Input::get('address');
    
                $contact->save();
    
                // $contact =  App\Contact::all();
    
                return view('contacts', compact('contact'));
            };
        }
```

I also have an edit function, which is not working, but I don't care about it.

I have edited my destroy function in several ways.

I'll list them here now, including the comments and the errors they returned.

Since every function is supposed to return the `delete.blade.php`, I am not writing this line in the following codes.

**destroy function 1**

```
//error: undefined variable in the findOrFail()
$contact = Contact::findOrFail($contact);
$contact->delete();
```

Independent of the parameter I want to pass in the findOrFail(), be it the $id, $name, or the uniques $phone or $email, the error is the same mentioned in the comment of the code.

**destroy function 2**

```
//FatalErrorException in ContactsController.php line 93:
//Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Contacts' not found
Contacts::where('id','=',$id);
$id->delete();
```

In this one and the next, I don't even know how to get rid of this error.

**destroy function 3**

```
//Same error as above
//Class not found
$contact = Contacts::where('id', '=', $id);
$contact->delete();
```

In the next, I included an `if` statement to check if things are going okay.

**destroy function 4**

```
//Class contacts not found
$id = contacts::where('id', $id)->first();
if ($id != null) {
    $id->delete();
return view('delete'); 
}else{
return view('delete')->with(['message'=> 'Contact not found']);
};
```

The next one returns an error that I don't understand.

**destroy function 5**

```
//Call to a member function delete() on null
//I don't know what that is supposed to mean
$id = Contact::all();
Contact::find($id) -> delete();
```

Now, the next piece of code is the one that feels that is the best, because it is returning the delete view, but is not deleting the entry in my table, not even using the forceDelete().

**destroy function 6**

```
//loading the view page, but not deleting the entry
// not even using forceDelete()
Contact::where('id', '=', '$id') 
    -> where('name', '=', '$name')
    -> delete();
```

Finally, just for fun, I guess, I'm posting this next line of code that takes my server down when I click the delete link in the table

```
//This line destroys my local server
//I have to up it again, using art serve command line
// $this -> destroy(Contact::get());
```

SO, I am having trouble in making my destroy function work.

**This is what I need**

I need some corrections in my functions, I'll be extra happy with just one correction in one of these functions.
Reiterating, NONE of these functions are working, each one of them return some kind of error, as you all can see in the comments provided in the code itself.

Like I said before, the **destroy function 6** is the one I feel that is the one that is going to work, because it is returning the view I want, it's just not deleting my entry in the table.

Also, I posted all this code because MAYBE the error is something that is coming all the way from the back.

Fell free to ask for other files, like model, migration and stuff.

**EDIT**

Here is my Contact model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    // not using an id field
    // could this be the error?
    // isn't laravel making an automatic id field?
    // dunno
    public $fillable = array('name', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'address');
    
    //added because of error at migration
    public $timestamps = false; 
}
```

As commented in the code, I had to add the `false` statement for the `timestamps`, because it was returning an error.

Now, here's something that kind of worked.

I took the **first destroy function** and applied it to my code.
The error was still the same, *undefined variable in the `findOrFail()`*.

So, I defined the variable, which I don't know if it's common practice.
Here's how it looks like.

```
$contact=Contact::first();
Contact::find($contact->id);
$contact->delete();
```

BUT, this piece of code deletes **the first** entry in my table, independent of where I click the delete button, which makes sense, that's a **first()** over there.

***So, since this is kind of working, what statement do I use to make it delete the entry I want it to?***

**End edit**

Sorry for the overload of code in a question.
And thank you all in advance.

Comment: Please put some error.

Comment: Hello, Pandhi. The errors are with the code blocks, along with other types of comments.

Comment: just some friendly advice: if you're learning Laravel, I suggest you learn on the most current version, which is 10. Version 5 is 8 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** **EDIT** **

You need to update your blade template where the Delete button is, to pass the contact id as part of the url

```
<tbody>
                @foreach($contact as $contact)                                                      
                    <tr class = "tableBody">
                        <td class = "id">       {{ $contact->id }}                                          </td>
                        <td class = "name">     {{ $contact->name }}                                        </td>
                        <td class = "lastname"> {{ $contact->lastname }}                                    </td>
                        <td class = "email">    {{ $contact->email }}                                       </td>
                        <td class = "phone">    {{ $contact->phone }}                                       </td>
                        <td class = "address">  {{ $contact->address }}                                     </td>
                        <td class = "edit">     <a href = "edit"> Edit </a>                                 </td>
                        <td class = "delete">   <a href = "delete/{{ $contact->id }}"> Delete </a>                             </td>
                    </tr>                       
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

Then Update your route for delete to include the id in the url

```
Route::get('delete/{id}', [
    'as' => 'delete', 'uses' => 'ContactsController@destroy'
]);
```

And then have your Controller destroy method accept the id

```
public function destroy($id)
{
   $contact = Contact::findOrFail($id);
   $contact->delete();
}
```

**Original Version**

Use $contact->id for this one. The findOrFail need the id to be passed.

**destroy function 1**

```
//error: undefined variable in the findOrFail()
$contact = Contact::findOrFail($contact->id);
$contact->delete();
```

**destroy function 2**

Seems like you do not have an import statement for Contacts class. Check the namespace of your Contacts class and add it as below at the top of your controller class:

```
use App\Contact;

$contact = Contact::where('id','=',$id)->get();
$contact->delete();
```

OR

```
Contact::destroy($id);
```

**destroy function 3**

Same as above. Add the import/use statement.

```
//Same error as above
//Class not found
$contact = Contact::where('id', '=', $id)->get();
$contact->delete();
```

Comment: I try to import the class using the 'use' statement, but the same error is displayed. Also, my model is in the root App directory.

Comment: Did you add `use App\Contact;` ? Also, I see 2 different names in your question. Is the class name `Contact` or `Contacts`? Use the correct import.

Comment: Yes, I added `use App\Contact; `. And I used the right name this time. I was testing in these codes, so I changed a lot of things before giving up.

Comment: Is it still not working? Can you post your updated code and any errors you might be getting?

Comment: Sorry for being late. The error is still the same, it's not recognizing the Contact class, even though I stated it in the file.

Comment: What is the namespace in the Contact class? I suggest you pick one of the options and provide the exact error you are getting. destroy function 1 is the most straightforward way. Also, please make sure that the $contact->id that you are trying to delete exists in the database. Otherwise, `findOrFail` simply throws `ModelNotFoundException`

Comment: Okay, I'll try to do that when I can. I don't remember the namespace in the class, I'm far from my work machine right now, but I'm almost sure it's `namespace App;`. I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Updated post with Model code, plus a few other things.

Comment: It works! I was stuck at this for almost a week now. Thank you so much for the help!